# how can I create special views search

Tags: 8

I create advanced search with views.
I want type one word and search it in 10 fields that I create in content and show all contents that use "word" in each fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an exposed view filter using 'global: combine fields filter', and select all the fields where you want to search the 'hello' (or wathever word you want) word. As long as you don't specify a content type, you will get all the elements that contain one of those fields with the written word.

To add the fields to the combine filter you need to have them on the fields you are showing in the view, but you can hide them if you want.

> edit:  this is a solution in D7 and but I think D8 may provide a very similar system.